# Where did Kamala Khan go when she put on the bracelet for the first time?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ms-marvel, ms-marvel-2022

In the first episode of Disney+ *Ms. Marvel*, Kamala goes to a different dimension when she puts the bracelet on. What's that place where she goes to?

The commentary for the episode says she falls into a portal where shadowy figures with glowing eyes are present.

Comment: It's likely that we're going to have to wait for more episodes to get an answer to this. Kamala's powers and origin have been dramatically changed (presumably because they didn't want to have to tie in with The Inhumans), so there's unlikely to be a clear answer from the comics.

Comment: Overvoid? Ancestral Plane? Field of Reeds? Gap Junction? So many  [intersectional planes of untethered consciousness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/262666/440) to choose from!

Answer (score 6):

##### Kamala had a vision of the past (the 1947 Partition of India).

It's not a vision of a different dimension. Kamala had a vision of the 1947 Partition of India, at the train station where Sana (Kamala's grandmother), Hasan (Sana's father), and Aisha (Sana's mother) were fleeing to Pakistan. The "shadowy figures" in the episode 1 vision were the huge crowd of people fleeing to Pakistan.

In episode 2, Kamala had another vision while wearing the bangle, but this time, of a woman gesturing at her. That woman was Aisha (as revealed in episode 5). In episode 3, Kamala had another vision, of a train with a sign that says "Karachi".

> During the fight, the bangle generates an image of a 1940s train that has profound significance for Khan's family.

<sup>- *Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*, page 314</sup>

> **Sana:** Did you see the train, *beta*? [...] Because I saw it too.

<sup>- *Ms. Marvel* S01E03</sup>

> **Kamala** (to Sana)**:** *Nani,* is it the same train? The one that we're seeing in the visions? Is it that train from that night?
> **Sana:** Yes.

<sup>- *Ms. Marvel* S01E04</sup>

> Kamala Khan's grandmother Sana also witnesses the vision of the train and asks the girl to visit her in Pakistan. She reveals that the train is from an incident during the British-mandated partition of India in the summer of 1947 in which Khan's great-grandparents, Aisha and Hasan, were forced to escape to the newly created nation of Pakistan. At the chaotic and overcrowded train station, Aisha disappeared, and her young daughter Sana became lost, only finding her way back to her father by following a mysterious "trail of stars."

<sup>- *Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*, page 314</sup>

The visions Kamala had in episodes 1, 2, and 3 were visions of being summoned back in time to the train station by Aisha (through the bangle). Aisha summoned Kamala (as revealed in episode 5) to guide Sana (who got lost in the crowd) back to Sana's father.

> When Najma stabs the bangle, it emits a burst of energy that transports Kamala Khan back to that pivotal moment in her family history from 1947 when her grandmother, Sana, and great-grandparents were boarding the train to Pakistan. Khan discovers that Aisha did not just disappear; she was murdered by Najma for refusing to return the Clandestines to the Noor Dimension. Khan also discovers that she herself created the field of stars that led her grandmother back to her great-grandfather.

<sup>- *Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*, page 315</sup>

This time-travel summoning is a causal loop, as Kamala ended up guiding her own grandmother ("she followed a trail of stars") to her great-grandfather, allowing them both to safely flee to Pakistan.

> **Sana:** [...] when the bangle was used the last time, it saved my life.

<sup>- *Ms. Marvel* S01E04</sup>

Answer (score 4):

As of the third episode, it is suggested that she is visiting the [Noor Dimension](https://decider.com/2022/06/22/ms-marvel-noor-dimension-djinn-clandestine-shang-chi/), the homeworld of a group that are sometimes known as Djinn when visiting Earth.

It has also been suggested that the scene resembles a distorted view of a crowded train, as in the situation where her grandmother Sana was separated from her family at the train station during their escape during the Partition, and how she followed a trail of stars to return, possibly tying in with her great-grandmother Aisha's disappearance and the vision of an oncoming train in the third episode, suggesting that Aisha is attempting to reach out to her descendant.